# É possível utilizar a LIB socket do python para fazer comunicações como um websocket?

Tags: python, socket, conexão, websocket

Olá, perdão se houver algum erro, eu estou criando um MMORPG com a engine **Construct 2** e ela só possui um plug-in de websockets, porém eu tentei usar a lib websockets do **Python**, mas acho que não está dando muito certo devido à minha inexperiência com esse assunto.

Porém eu não consigo achar algo relevante na internet sobre essa lib incluindo criações de jogos multiplayer, eu consegui o resultado que eu queria fazendo um programa com websocket, mas está travando muito a client, e eu suponho que o emulador esteja consumindo muita memória RAM, pois o lag só ocorre ao ter 2 ou mais players conectados.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, desde sujestões utilizando a lib websocket, exemplos, ou indicações de outras libs, ou outras tecnologias sem ser Python, pois ja usei **Node.js** e não consegui por não achar algo que tivesse **Thread** no Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondendo só a questão "É possível utilizar a LIB socket do python para fazer comunicações como um websocket?" Sim - é possível.

Afinal, websockets são um protocolo de mais alto nível, que usam sockets internamente.

Agora, se você perguntar se você "deve" fazer isso, a resposta é um claro e sonoro **não**.

E a lógica para isso é simples: ao fazer algo com sockets puros, você tem que cuidar de *todos* os detalhes você mesmo, diretamente no seu código: como saber os tamanhos de cada mensagem, ler e interpretar cabeçalhos de início de conexão, e persistir o estado de cada conexão, gerenciar multiplos clientes, e essa lista poderia continuar para várias outras coisas que são resolvidas quando vocẽ usa um protocolo de mais alto nível que já está definido (no caso, o websockets), e já existe uma implementação para esse protocolo (no caso, a lib de websockets).

Se essa implementação de websockets não for boa, e você for uma pessoa com muita experiência de redes, muita experiẽncia em pelo menos uma linguagem de programação, e pelo menos um conhecimento médio de Python, então, sim, re-criar a funcionalidade de websockets usando sockets puros poderia ser uma opção interessante. Mas note que apenas se você responder "sim" para as quatro coisas!

Dada a continuação da sua pergunta, parece que você só considerou a alternativa por que ainda não achou a melhor forma de usar usar a biblioteca de websockets já existente, e você dá a entender que não é um expert em programação de rede - então fica valendo o "não", não faça isso! :-)

Tente, ao invés disso,  criar outras perguntas, mais específicas, colocando código completo que as pessoas possam usar como exemplo, de o que não está funcionando aí para o pessoal aqui poder ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado !!! Consegui aqui, depois de uma luta eu consegui